# Can you delete an org created through environment hub?

Tags: environment-hub

I created an org using the environment hub for packaging. But my mistake gave the wrong username for the org admin. Can I change the username on this org or delete this org and recreate the admin credentials?

I really want to reuse the URL for this org. Appreciate any help.

Comment: are you able to login to the new org as admin ? If yes are you not able to change the username from user detail page ?

Comment: yes i can login. but the username field is not editable.